# Adding additional ViewController tabs to TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I created a new Obj-C "tabbed application" using XCode 6.1.1 on Yosemite.

I have read through the documentation and online tutorials about UITabBarController settings.  I have tried to adjust TabBarItems, viewControllers array, and whatever else I could find and I'm really stuck.  The IB is NOT allowing me to ctrl-drag from the TabBarController to the additional VCs that I want to link.

All I want to do is add additional tabsBarItems to my tabBar, and when each tab is tapped, it opens a different view controller.

I have created 2 view controllers ("thirdVC" and "fourthVC") in my storyboard in addition to the "firstViewController" and "secondViewController" that were created by default when I started the tabbed application project, but the 3rd and 4th aren't linked in code or in the storyboard to the tabBar in any way.

How do I add additional tabBar viewController items to the tabBar.viewControllers array (that isn't mutable), get them to appear in the tabBar, either in code or in the storyboard?  I'd prefer to learn how to do it with code, but I'd also like to know if this can be done in the IB.  Please provide a code snippet solution (not just a description) and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, so I rebuilt a custom TabBarController to understand.

You can find the sample code here:
https://github.com/damienromito/CustomTabBarController

[image]